# Unable to send mails on the same thread

Tags: java, email

I am trying to send the email on the same thread by passing the threadID in the "In-Reply-To" and "Reference" parameter of setHeader method but the problem is that the mail is sent but not on the same thread.
Below is the code snippet that I am using
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
String Subject = "Re:Test Java Mail API";
String ThreadID = "PSBPR02MB43444E8F5DA233F48E0CCF9ED7309@PSBPR02MB4344.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com"
    

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setHeader("In-Reply-To", ThreadID);
    message.setHeader("References", ThreadID);
    message.setHeader("Subject", Subject);
    message.setContent(str, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: You could find the threadID before calling your send mail method and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: @Sascha,thanks for the help.I have tried this by getting the messageID and then passing the same messageID but it is still sending the message on different thread. PFB the link for the modified code.                                                                                              https://pastebin.com/TG8Q9hHJ

Comment: I fix the thread by using the built in `MimeMessage replyMessage = (MimeMessage) emailMessage.reply(repyToAll)`. You could do that just to see which headers are being set to fix the thread.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want the mail in the client to be displayed in a thread? Then it seems you are not really in control of it and can only hope the mail client does it the way you want it to. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36251102/2135838)

Comment: Maybe [this info](https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) could help. But really, it seems that some mail servers [also meddle with the message ids](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8297927/2135838).